# What does pelican taste like?

Tags: meat, flavor

Has anyone tried Pelican before? Or know what it tastes like? I had a look around on other sites but couldn't find anything.

Oddly curious as to the answer - thought about it once and can't get it out of my head.

Comment: A similar  has been asked on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/3geqmv/why_dont_people_hunt_pelicans/ where the answer was 'Pelican is unpleasantly fishy. Not in the sense of "Oh, this tastes like fish" but in the sense of "Oh, this tastes like fish that's been left out too long and shouldn't have been eaten."

I grew up in Louisiana. It's a mistake one only has to make once.' With no other reference source I won't post this as an answer.

Comment: I've upvoted answers based on things like that @Spagirl, it might be the best answer we're going to get.

Comment: @Spagirl It's at least as good as the existing answer ("probably the same as other fish-eating birds").

Comment: Upvoted this even as a vegetarian - if you have to be carnists, be equal opportunity carnists.

Comment: I thought I'd seen a passage about eating pelican in a book, but when I dug the book up it was actually cormorant that was so described.  Sorry bout that.  Also, I agree with @rackandboneman, it seems an interesting question even to a vegetarian.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've never had pelican, but I have eaten a number of fish-eating birds, like loon/duck. There is a sameness in taste in fish eating birds: oily meat, dark, with bad fish flavor. Not advised unless closest store to buy food is more than 3 days walk away.

Answer (score 2):

Many years ago I saw a number of East Africans (Kenya) eat pelicans and it had been salted for a few days and it still tasted like fish. On the other hand the tribe at Lake Naivasha ate flamingo and it tasted just like flamingo should taste.

Comment: And just what should flamingo taste like? They are filter feeders which take in a range of algae, diatoms, small pelagic crustaceans and invertebrates, so I would expect them to be less fishy than pelican.

Comment: I now have a vision in my head of capturing a flamingo by yanking its standing leg with the crook of a walking stick.

Comment: @LaconicDroid that's not far off from how my family caught our much more traditional poultry when it was time to process them.